# GET request is sent twice in express JS

Tags: express

I have a loop, that is making 19 calls to a GET url.

```
generateMonthlyPNG(recap) {
    for (const meter of meters) { // 19 elements
        let url = process.env.BASE_URL + "operations/" + recap.operation.name + "/meters/" + meter + "/monthly";
        promises.push(this.makePngScreenshot(recap, url, meter, "monthly"));
    }
    return promises
}
```

With :

```
async makePngScreenshot(recap, url, meterId, filename) {
        axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
        const destination = "public/images/" + recap.operation.name + "/" + recap.date_ini + "_" + recap.date_end + "/" + meterId
        // console.log("Creating image in: " + destination)
        return new Pageres({ delay: 2, filename: filename })
            .src(url, ['1300x650'], { crop: true })
            .dest(destination)
            .run()
}

app.get("/operations/:operation/meters/:meter/monthly", async (req, res) => { // Used to generate PNG from graph
console.log(".")
}
```

`generateMonthlyPNG` is only called once

Weird thing is that I have 19 meters, and I print 38 dots (.), so, I duplicate all my calls, I don't understand why.

Any idea ?

Comment: What does `new Pageres().src(url)dest(...).run()` do?  I see you're also passing it the same url.  I would guess that it may also be accessing that url along with your `axios.get(url)`.

Comment: it create a PNG from web page. oooh It could be the error, let me check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are accessing the URL twice, once with:

```
axios.get(url)
```

and again with:

```
new Pageres({ delay: 2, filename: filename })
        .src(url, ['1300x650'], { crop: true })
        .dest(destination)
        .run()
```

This will cause the underlying code to request the same page twice.

Comment: yep, my bad ! It did the trick ! Thanks mate !